# Find unknown vector given a set of known angles and vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an unknown vector, $v$, and a set of known vectors, $k_i$, and a known set of angles $\theta_i$ between $k_i$ and $v$, all in $\mathbb{R}^n$

I can project another set of vectors $p_{k_i}$, each at cosine angle $\theta_i$ to $k_i$

I do this by projecting a random vector orthogonally into the subspace for $v$ and than adding a $1/tan(\theta_i)v$ to that orthogonal vector.  I confirm this is correct by checking the cosine angle.  (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15011/generate-a-random-variable-with-a-defined-correlation-to-an-existing-variables) for more info) )

Not sure if the projected vectors help, but I've been trying to find some way to use them to help find the unknown vector $v$.  It's interesting that I see qualities about them that seem like they might be useful especially in those $k_i$ with high cosine similarity to $v$ (ie, close to $1$).  Other than that though, no luck so far.

Is there a way to find $v$, even if probabilistically?  If it helps, I also know a fair amount about the distribution of $v$ (mean, std)

Comment: One idea I'm noodling right now is finding the intersection of subspaces.

Comment: How many vectors to you have in your "set" ? $n$ is the minimum.

Comment: Maybe this is more a prob/stats question than a linear algebra question.  For example, since we know the mean, we already know the most probable vector is the expected value, ignoring the other info.  With the other information we can probably do better.

Comment: You haven't answered my question...

Comment: I think the problem description made clear that n is a variable, and the answer is that the probability is very likely directly correlated to it, at least relative to the number of known $k_i$ vectors.

Comment: I just wanted to say that if the number of constraints is less than the dimension $n$ of the space, you cannot conclude.

Comment: Well, it depends on the constraints, right.  For example, one constraint might be that all components must be positive whole numbers, not repeating and less than n.  But 'concluding' is not required as probabilistic is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Dump the angles, and trade them for inner products. You'll need to nominate a length $L > 0$ for $v$ as well as the angles (otherwise, at best, you'll reduce $v$ to a ray from the origin). You can then write,
$$\langle v, k_i\rangle = L\|k_i\|\cos(\theta_i) =: \alpha_i.$$
The system $\langle v, k_i \rangle = \alpha_i$ is then a system of linear equations, but the (non-linear) restriction $\|v\| = L$ is not covered by the these linear equations, and must therefore be included as well. The solution to this non-linear system will be the set of all applicable vectors $v$ with the given length $L$. To get all such vectors $v$, regardless of length, take all positive scalar multiples of these solutions.

Comment: This is what I originally did, and it makes perfect sense, but I was wondering if there was a fuzzier / less accurate though perhaps more practically useful approach.

Comment: I'll try it again, scipy has some linear optimizersI didn't investigate enough.  Thanks!